# Modx Revolution with several MIGX TVS in same template. Why am I getting "max_user_connexions" xpdo error in Firefox 58.0.1?

Tags: firefox, modx, modx-revolution, xpdo, migx

I am working on a site in MODX 2.6.1-pl and have a template that uses 7 different MIGX template variables.

Everything seemed to work fine to work fine initially, but now some pages cause many (several hundred) of the following xpdo errors when I try to edit them **in Firefox 58.0.1**:

```
[2018-02-05 11:34:55] (ERROR in xPDOConnection::connect @ /home/user/public_html/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 3116) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User user_modx already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

It would appear this is only happening on pages that contain large amounts of data stored in the MIGX TVs.

Also, this error does not occur in:

- Chrome  64.0.3282.140
- Safari  10.1.2 (10603.3.8)
- Opera   50.0.2762.67

Why is this happening?

Is it due to how the new Firefox handles Ajax or something?

How can I work around this?

Am I asking too much of MIGX? Would it be better to put all my data in a custom table and use MIGXdb instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer : Firefox was blocking some of the calls because I was logged in with HTTPS security exception.

I tried without using an HTTPS connection and it works.